# How to re-initialize the Docusign PHP API with different credentials

Tags: php, docusignapi

We have a case where we need to check envelope status in two separate Docusign accounts. If we don't get status in the first, we want to check the second.

I'm having trouble getting the API to re-initialize with the credentials of our second account. I'm calling this snippet with the new variables:

```
require_once('docusign/SignatureApi.php');
$IntegratorsKey = "abcd";
$UserID = "dave@account.com";
$Password = "xxxxx";
$_apiEndpoint = $Endpoint;
$_apiWsdl = "docusign/api/APIService.wsdl";
$api_options =  array('location'=>$_apiEndpoint,'trace'=>true,'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
$api = new APIService($_apiWsdl, $api_options);
$api->setCredentials("[" . $IntegratorsKey . "]" . $UserID, $Password);

$res = RequestEnvelopStatuses($envelopes);
$envelopeStatuses = $res->RequestStatusesResult;

if(!count($envelopeStatuses->EnvelopeStatuses->EnvelopeStatus)){
  // If we did not find envelopes, check other account
  $IntegratorsKey = "wxyz";
  $UserID = "fred@altaccount.com";
  $Password = "xxxxx";
  $api->setCredentials("[" . $IntegratorsKey . "]" . $UserID, $Password);
  // retry request
  $res = RequestEnvelopStatuses($envelopes);
  $envelopeStatuses = $res->RequestStatusesResult;
}
```

It doesn't return an error, but won't return envelope status either. It seems to still use the first credentials (guessing). The second attempt always seems to return whatever the first attempt did.

Is there a better / preferred way to do this?

Comment: Can you show more code than that?  Show the first call the the API, and your second that is causing you troubles

Comment: Have you just tried instantiating another object rather than reusing `$api`? Where is `$envelopes` defined?  It would seem if you are calling the same `RequestEnvelopeStatuses` without a change in this value, that you would get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not look like the proper way to get the envelope status.  Maybe that's why you are not finding them and trying to look again?

```
// Create a filter using account ID and today as a start time 
$envStatusFilter = new EnvelopeStatusFilter();
$envStatusFilter->AccountId = $AccountID;
$beginDateTime = new EnvelopeStatusFilterBeginDateTime();
$beginDateTime->_ = todayXsdDate(); // note that this helper function
                                    // is in CodeSnippets/include/utils.php
                                    // in the PHP SDK
$envStatusFilter->BeginDateTime = $beginDateTime;

// Send
$requestStatusesparams = new RequestStatuses();
$requestStatusesparams->EnvelopeStatusFilter = $envStatusFilter;
$response = $api->RequestStatuses($requestStatusesparams);
```